# UE5 rendering bug: Severe rendering issues

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit, unreal

I have been working on my game for quite a while now, everything was fine until I booted up my game and find out that the rendering is completely messed up:

here's a screenshot:

[image]

and note that this is LIT and This is the infamous rural Australia level.

what happened in the session before the issue appeared:
experimented with culling, here’s what I did:
I setup a culling volume then, set the culling distance to around 10000 but the size was maxed out (more than 9 billion)

In the image the culling volume was removed, however the engine was still culling although there wasn’t a culling volume.

notes:
I can see through things, and from surface level it looks worse than what the screenshot is displaying

The only type of the light that works is a directional light, other types of light simply don't work.

Any help?

<3

what I tried:

- Removed the culling volume, but the game is still culling, although there's no culling volume anymore.
- Build every thing.
- setup a culling volume with normal values hoping that it would reset the culling.
- contacted ChatGP, but it didn't know what to do.
- I fired up another level but the problems are still there.
- I fired up another project and the issues are gone, so it's a project specific issue.